# Error sending data to table pentaho-postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, pentaho

I'm trying to send some data to a table in postgres. But it's not working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjIIJ.png)

Already check postgres version, pentaho version, jar version. I've been able to conect and send data to a mysql table, but not postgres.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIpiH.png)

Send data from csv archive to a table in postgrest with pentaho.

**Solved**

- i found the problem. I just refresh the database cache and it worked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

it seems that in your table, you don't have the column employee_name to insert the values, does your table have this column?

Comment: Yes, i found the problem. I just refresh the database cache and it worked.

Comment: Good! probably you have an cached version of the table which did not contains that column.